# Какой запрос в PostgreSQL может вывести наибольшие 20% из таблицы?

Tags: postgresql

Необходимо выбрать 20% записей с наивысшей Price за дату 2022-02-03.
не понимаю какая должна быть структура запроса

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: `WHERE NTILE(5)=1`

Answer (score 0):

Оценить количество строк за дату. Выбрать строки за дату, сортировать по убыванию price. Поставить лимит 0.2*количество строк за дату.